# Ambiguity on Topology Normality vs Algebraic Normality

Tags: algebraic-topology

The following is a question from Munkres Topology:
Let $f : G → H$ and $g : H → K$ be homomorphisms; assume $f$ is
surjective. If $x_0 ∈ G$, and if $ker(g)$ is the least normal subgroup of $H$ containing
$f(x_0)$, then $ker(g ◦ f )$ is the least normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ containing $ker(f)$
and $x_0$.

Then he gives the following hint: Show that $f(N)$ is normal; conclude that $ker(g ◦ f ) = f ^{−1}(ker (g)) ⊂
f ^{−1} f (N) = N$

I am confused on what he means by normality in the question. My understanding is that when the question talks about the "least normal subgroup" it is referring to the algebraic definition of normality. But when it says "show that $f(N)$ is normal. . . " I am not sure if wants me to use the algebraic definition or topological definition (ie a $T_4$ space). Earlier in the chapter there was some talk about Normal spaces, so I am really confused what Munkres is saying here.

Comment: Sounds to me like "normal" means the algebraic sense. There seems to be no reference to a topology in this case.

Comment: I agree, no topology here. The assumption is that $f$ and $g$ are homomorphisms between groups, not that they are continuous maps between topological spaces. This question is purely about algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are confused because Rotman twice writes "(least) normal subgroup" and then asks to show that *$f(N)$ is normal* instead of *$f(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $H$*.

The topological concept of normality would not make any sense here. We do not have any topology on $f(N)$ (nor on $H \supset f(N)$). Rotman definitely means the group theoretical concept of normality.

Comment: Yes, This makes sense, thank you. It was definitely confusing because he did not specify what $f(N)$ was a normal subgroup of.